Как вызвать в функции случайную функцию?
Хочу вывести на печать случайным образом содержимое в функции.. получаю сообщение:
<coroutine object process_start_command.<locals>.x at 0x0000024E0D550240>

программа:
import random
import randomfun

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    async def x():
        if True:
            f = [randomfun.ran_fun1, randomfun.ran_fun2]
            rand_x = random.choice(f)
            rand_x()
    await message.answer(f"{x}")

файл randomfun:
from aiogram import types

async def ran_fun1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text='Это рандомное сообщение 1')

async def ran_fun2(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text='Это рандомное сообщение 2')

Я конкретно запутался, явно что то не то вызываю.

Ну как минимум нету вызова функции x и нету await у вызовов асинхронных функций

await rand_x(message)

Это не простая функция, это корутина. Попробуйте await, да.

@CrazyElf ну всё-таки это функция, которая при вызове вернёт корутину. Каким образом автор получил корутину без вызова функции — для меня загадка

ну не бейте сильно... @andreymal
Вызвал функцию x()  - пишет ту же ошибку.. что значит нет await у вызова асин функции... когда она есть? await message.answer() ?

@Kavermoki а вас не смущает, что кроме message.answer в вашем коде есть ещё целых три асинхронных функции?

@andreymal можно попросить Вас показать пример на 1 асинхронной функции...?

Во втором сверху комментарии уже показали (и заодно забытый аргумент добавили)

@andreymal я добавил await rand_x(message) для функции async def x(): и получаю уже  <function process_start_command.<locals>.x at 0x000002D52240BEE0>

Что говорит о том, что функцию x вы так до сих пор и не вызвали

Будем исправлять поэтапно.
Для начала, у вас есть вложенная функция x, но вы ее не вызываете, а выводите как сообщение. Чтобы вызвать функцию, нужно добавить скобки: x(). Т.к. функция асинхронная, то нужно добавить еще и await. Если бы функция возвращала текст сообщения, можно было бы написать вот так:
await message.answer(text=f"{await x()}")

или проще:
await message.answer(text=await x())

Т.к. функция у вас ничего не возвращает, а пытается вызвать внутри функцию, которая сама отправляет сообщение, то нужно просто вызвать как await x().
Далее, у вас в rand_x попадает асинхронная функция, ее нужно вызывать как асинхронную функцию (с await). При этом все функции в списке у вас ожидают параметр message, его нужно при вызове передать. Итого, вызов случайной функции должен выглядеть так:
await rand_x(message)

Целиком будет что-то такое:
import random
import randomfun


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    async def x():
        if True:
            f = [randomfun.ran_fun1, randomfun.ran_fun2]
            rand_x = random.choice(f)
            await rand_x(message)
    await x()

Если убрать бессмысленную вложенность функции и бессмысленную проверку на True, то получится так:
import random
import randomfun


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    f = [randomfun.ran_fun1, randomfun.ran_fun2]
    rand_x = random.choice(f)
    await rand_x(message)


Если у вас функции ничего кроме вывода сообщений не делают, то проще не список функций хранить, а список сообщений:
import random


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    messages = ['Это рандомное сообщение 1', 'Это рандомное сообщение 2']
    random_message = random.choice(f)
    await message.answer(text=random_message)


Спасибо тебе огромное за объяснение!
